# How can I recover data from two good disks in a RAID 10?

Tags: data-recovery, raid10

I have a Lacie Ethernet RAID disk NAS box.  I configured the 4 disks in a RAID 10 config.  The Lacie unit will not let me make CIFS connections to the box stating "Shared Folders: Not Ready" but I can see that the data is still there.  I have done the troubleshooting route with resetting the system.  Now I am in data recovery mode.

If I take two disks (one mirrored stripe) out of the Lacie box, assuming the data is intact, how can I go about recovering the data since it is part of a stripe?  Could I connect the two drives to a windows system?  Or a Linux system?  Would they been seen as a stripe?  Or as individual drives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the world of proprietary NAS boxes. First, if you really need the data, send the drives off to a data recovery firm. Anything you do at this point risk loosing everything.

Now that said, I don't know if Lacie used Win, Linux, or a proprietary type of raid.
If it's their own blend, and they can't make it work, then you are out of luck. 
Maybe someone else can go into detail on how you do raid on Win Embedded.

If they used off the shelf Linux in that box, then you might be able to rebuild the raid by connecting all the drives to a normal computer and booting a live cd. Do a search on the "mdadm" command.

Comment: In addition: you will need both stripes, otherwise you will only have half of your data (and most likely you won't be able to access any, as the partition tables are also striped). The mirrors of these stripes just provide the redundancy.

Comment: I guess you are right.  I was thinking if I could just take a disk out of the device and mount it in a Linux Live CD one at a time and just copy each disk over - but the stripe complicates this.