# Recommendation of Data Recovery Company

Tags: hardware, hard-drive

Have a customer that temporarily moved his work to a 2.5" WD Passport drive without a problem.  Long story short drive no longer mounts on any computer.  Issue is that he has a current project there.

Windows does not mount drive and OS X says "The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer."

Any recommendation on a reliable data recovery company?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just used [Secure Data Recovery](http://www.securedatarecovery.com/) to recover our Exchange Database when 2 out of 3 drives in our RAID5 array failed overnight and our backup was worthless.

It was expensive, and took a few days, but they successfully recovered all our data with no Exchange corruption. So that was awesome.

They did require a wire transfer for final payment, which I did not know up front and thought was weird. But it worked out just fine.

Comment: If you don't mind, around how much was each drive?

Comment: It was a 3 drive RAID5 array. We paid about $1800 up front for them to come pick up the drives, look at them right away and get us a quote within 3 hours. They quoted us $2500 non refundable deposit to start attempting recovery and $7500 if recovery was successful. We opted for their expedited plan where they work 24/7 on the recovery. This was a flat +40% increase. Total cost ended up around $17,000. It was expensive, but it was 7 years worth of email, so we felt it was worthwhile. (Prices are rounded because it was a few months ago and I forget exact numbers.)

Comment: They didn't price it per drive. I imagine RAID recovery is different/more difficult than recovering from a single drive, so I assume the price for a single drive would be much cheaper, especially if you did not need to expedite the initial analysis and actual recovery.

Comment: Thanks!  I now know for future customers and useful for recommending off site backups.

Comment: It did make it a lot easier for me to get funding for proper backup software and storage, so that was the one good outcome of this...

Answer (score 2):

[Kroll Ontrack](http://www.ontrackdatarecovery.co.uk/) are generally very highly regarded. I've personally seen them recover everything from a totally trashed RAID array.

Answer (score 1):

From actual experience I gained during this question [How can I recover data from two good disks in a RAID 10?](https://serverfault.com/questions/180233/how-can-i-recover-data-from-two-good-disks-in-a-raid-10)

I used http://www.seagatedatarecovery.com/ - They were a data recovery company bought out by Seagate a few years ago. You know the company must be good if Seagate bought them! They have an office in Chicago (so I could drive to it instead of ship it to them) and California.

As for cost, as expected I paid $4000 to recover data from a corrupted RAID 1+0  $1000 per disk.  It took about two weeks but I got all the data back and saved my backside.